# Problema MODELO E/R (Entidad/Relacion)

Tags: base-de-datos, modelorelacional, diagrama-er

Estoy creando un diagrama E/R para guardar datos de una competición, y tengo una entidad que es **partidos** y otra **equipos** y aquí se da que un equipo juega muchos partidos, pero un partido SIEMPRE lo juegan 2 equipos. No tengo claro como poder relacionarlo para que a la hora de pasarlo al modelo relacional para la creación de la BBDD la tabla partidos herede el ID de equipos dos veces (equipo_local y equipo_visitante).

No sé si puede surgir una doble relación 1:N entre las entidades(equipos y partidos) para propagar dos veces el ID de equipos.

Quiero que quede así en el modelo relacional pero no se la manera correcta de plasmarlo en el modelo E/R, si alguien tiene alguna idea la agradecería, gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por cómo has planteado tu modelo relacional, partirías de un modelo ER simplificado (presupongo los atributos) tal que así:

[image: Modelo ER propuesto]

Lo que haces a continuación, como ambas relaciones tienen cardinalidad 1:N, es propagar el `equipo_visitante` e `equipo_local` a `partidos`.

Personalmente, añadiría una restricción adicional tal que `equipo_local` e `equipo_visitante` no pudieran coincidir, ya que un equipo no debería poder jugar contra sí mismo.

Answer (score 0):

ese modelo relacional creo que se vería así en modelo E/R

[image: Partido-1-Jugar-2-Equipo]

Te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a http://mysql.conclase.net/curso/?cap=002# (capitulo 2, ahí explican bien el modelo E/R)